In Windows 10/11, where was the change to deny write/create directory access under "Program Files" documented?
For years, I have often created folders/edited files within %ProgramFiles(x86)% and %ProgramFiles%, bypassing whatever warnings are given.

However, when trying to create a folder now, I get error
Destination Folder Access Denied - is this a UAC prompt, or is Microsoft using the blue-and-yellow shield for issues beyond UAC now?    
Similarly, I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException from C# code:
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\test");




Where was this change to deny write/create directory access under %ProgramFiles% documented?

When did it start, and is there a Group Policy to make exceptions to it?
Is this a difference introduced in Windows 10, or prior editions?


“ Is this a UAC prompt?” - No; It’s a prompt indicating you don’t have elevated permissions and it’s requesting you provide them by hitting the button with the UAC symbol (Continue). “ where was this change to deny write/create directory access under "Program Files" documented?” - 25 years ago with the release of Windows Vista. Write access to the Program Files directory has required Administrator access for 25 years. “Is this a difference between Windows 10 and 11?” - No; Windows 10 and Windows 11 is identical in this way. As is Windows 7, Vista, and Windows XP. Stop using protected folders.

UAC was originally introduced with XP, enchanced with Vista and 7, improved with 8, 10 and 11. Program Files has been a folder that as required elevated permissions for more than 25 years. Microsoft has recommended AppData for more than 20 years as Windows has introduced Protected directories like Program Files, Windows directory, and others in newer versions. My advice is stop storing application data, in the application’s directory contained within Program Files.

I'm pretty sure I was freely able to create folders in Program Files without elevation at some point in the past.  Do you know where this might be documented?

In every programming book that was targeted to Windows developers since UAC was introduced. Program Files being restricted to elevated permissions is well documented. Do I have a specific website or documentation handy, I absolutely do not have that handy, but UAC has been around since Windows Vista. Windows 7 and Windows Vista really changed it compared to Windows XP. For this to have been something you remember it must have been on Windows 2000. You can avoided the authorization error by elevating the permissions on the application to that of an Administrator or by NOT using that directory

I believe this started on Windows NT 4, where, by default users have only read access to program files, and administrators have read/write. Note that windows NT4 is a business OS and it was all the way up to Windows 2000 that there were 2 separate OSses. 1 for consumer and one for business. Windows XP and up have different versions of the OS, home vs premium/pro, and in windows XP home used the old structure, where premium used the new structure. I believe in Windows 8 the rights were changed to increase security. So TL;DR: windows 8.

Most likely you had disabled UAC or set it to to a lower level. Or you had modified the default permissions of Program Files directories. As you only have to modify it once you may have forgotten this over time.

I do believe it is Windows 10 where TRUSTED INSTALLER is the default owner of program Files, which changed the user rights too. Before that, it was the user that was first created at windows install. And if your own user is owner, you don't need write access in the settings to write to a folder.

The “original” owner is the Administrators group, not the first user in the system and also not the Administrator built-in account.

It has been a LONG time since I was able to create folders inside Program Files without elevated access. I agree with Ramhound on this.

There is no Group Policy to modify the foundational ACLs because it's operating as intended per the ACLs - see either the Advanced Security properties or icacls $env:ProgramFiles || icacls ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}. From a security standpoint, you want %ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles(x86) to require Admin authorization to modify subfolders and files

On a single-user Windows PCs, you are usually an Administrator. That means you can do just about anything, including saving files to C:\ or C:\Program Files\.
Before UAC (which came with Vista, not XP), being an admin meant acting as an admin all the time. Every program you launched could also do just about anything. Not so great regarding malware and whatnot. So UAC was introduced.
With UAC (User Account Control), being an admin no longer means acting as one all the time. Instead, when you log in, under the hood, you actually log in twice: Once with admin rights, and once with regular user rights. Normal day-to-day work does not require admin rights, after all. Only when you specifically launch a process elevated does it get admin rights.
Regular users are mostly restricted to their own user folder, and have been since Windows 2000. In fact, Windows XP has many similar or equal ACL entries on C:\ and C:\Program Files\_ compared to my Windows 10 system.
tl;dr: There was no change. It’s “always” been like that.
If it was different for you, you may have inadvertently changed Program Files’ ACL in the past, which may or may not have been reverted during an update.

A note regarding C:\: The ACL still allows all authenticated users to create folders there today.

Not technically correct, and I talk from experience. Yes, the ACL has not changed in the form of security rights for a long time, but ownership changed to Trusted Installer. When this change happened, new windows installs would now prompt for administrative access everytime I wanted to install a program to program files, and before that, it would only do that if it also had to write to the registry. Before this change, if a game was installed to program files, as long as you were in the administrators group, you could run it. After the change, it would always request admin access.

The ownership change is irrelevant. It only means you can no longer change ACLs unless explicitly permitted to do so. There is no other effect of this change. When or whether Windows prompts to elevate a program (installer or otherwise) is a whole different topic with sometimes surprising complexity—and also entirely unrelated to the ownership change. Your memory is probably inaccurate.

That's not true. If you are owner of a folder, and then remove your user, but the Creator Owner is still there, windows will treat this as acceptable. If you change the owner afterwards, suddenly you get a UAC prompt for just accessing the folder. This is because the Creator Owner basically grants rights to whoever is owner. In the past, this was by default, full Control.

What is not true? Please provide a concrete scenario. Remember the following facts: Unless elevated, you are not in the Administrators group. Ownership only affects ACL operations, not file/folder operations. Try it out: Create a folder, be owner, remove all ACL entries. You will be denied access. Try adding the Administrators group. You will still be denied access.

Unless you also add Creator Owner. If you then are owner, the creator owner rights DO apply. This is how it used to be set before the change in V1607.

Except, of course, one is not the owner of Program Files. Which brings us back to the question, and again, my answer: What about it is not true? Please elaborate.

Yeah, exactly my point. one is not the owner of Program files ANYMORE. This has changed since V1607, where TrustedInstaller became the owner.

Hmm, okay, I started to doubt things, so I installed Windows 7 and Creator Owner is there, but Trusted Installer is still owner. The source I read online stated that TrustedOwner was changed since V1607. Sorry for the confusion.

It would still be nice to find actual documentation of this from when restricting such rights was introduced, presumably in Vista or XP.  I cannot find one; please let me know if you do.

Documentation about what? UAC? Because that’s the change, and it certainly is documented. Everything else is (effectively) the exact same.

I have not been able to find documentation on how UAC is intended to work against the Program Files folders.  This describes the concept https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835561(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN but doesn't mention Program Files.

That would not (need to) be documented explicitly. The perceived change is merely a logical consequence of UAC. Program Files has been read-only for regular users since Windows 2000 (I checked).
